# What is the best way to check if element exist on page?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with cells containing data, on which i do operations. I am simply checking condition like:

```
(ExtractTextFromElement(duoqTable, duoqRowNumber, 3, "'duoqTable'").Contains("Europe") ||
  ExtractTextFromElement(duoqTable, duoqRowNumber, 3, "'duoqTable'").Contains("Russia")
```

The problem is that this IWebElement sometimes may disappear and if  I am inside this condition block, the exception occurs. I could do additional check, if the element exists before every condition statement but it seems ineffective. Is there any better way?

Comment: Could you make a wrapper method named `TryExtractTextFromElement` which has a `try/catch` block around this statement and returns an empty array when this exception is caught?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use find Elements method instead of find Element then you will not get exception.  Find Elements returns list of Web Elements you need to check the size of it.

```
if driver.findElements(By.className("xyz").size()>0
   driver.findElements(By.className("xyz").get(0).getText();
else
   System.out.println("No element found")
```

The above code will not throw any exception and no need to use try/catch block.